# R exact selection based on %in%

Tags: r

I am having some trouble doing a simple operation.

What I want is to simply select the rows, grouped by `id`, that have all of the values `(-1, -2, -3, -4)`, and apply a tag based on this condition.

```
   id time
1   1   -4
2   1   -3
3   1   -2
4   1   -1
5   2   -1
6   2   -2
7   3   -1
8   3   -3
9   4   -1
10  4   -2
11  4   -3
12  4   -4
```

Intuitively I was going for

```
rb[rb$time %in% c(-1, -2, -3, -4), ]
```

However, when I do that, all `id` are selected. So, the `%in%` operator uses the `OR` `|` operator.

So, I thought I could do this then, to use the `AND &` operator

```
rb[rb$time == -1 & 
 rb$time == -2 & 
 rb$time == -3 & 
 rb$time == -4, ]
```

But it does not work.

Any clue how I could tag or subset these `id`, such that

```
   id time tag
1   1   -4   1
2   1   -3   1
3   1   -2   1
4   1   -1   1
5   2   -1   0
6   2   -2   0
7   3   -1   0
8   3   -3   0
9   4   -1   1
10  4   -2   1
11  4   -3   1
12  4   -4   1
```

Comment: "However, when I do that, all id are selected." - I think this is expected as all your ids fulfil the requirement that they should have one of those values -4,-3,-2 or -1

Comment: The reason why your conditional indexing didn't work is that the logical AND operator says that the value has to meet all of the conditions i.e.: it would have to be both a -1,-2,-3,-4. If you'd change it to logical OR, it gives back the correct values, since the condition could be translated as: the value should be either -1 or -2 or -3 or -4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(tag = all(c(-1, -2, -3, -4) %in% time) * 1)

      id  time   tag
   <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     1    -4     1
 2     1    -3     1
 3     1    -2     1
 4     1    -1     1
 5     2    -1     0
 6     2    -2     0
 7     3    -1     0
 8     3    -3     0
 9     4    -1     1
10     4    -2     1
11     4    -3     1
12     4    -4     1
```

And the same with `base R` could be:

```
with(df, ave(time, id, FUN = function(x) all(c(-1, -2, -3, -4) %in% x) * 1))
```

Comment: great, I did know the `all` function, it's very handy!

Answer (score 1):

One of many base R options is to use `aggregate` (we could also rename and convert to integer to get 0 or 1, but booleans seem better fit for the purpose):

```
tags <- aggregate(df$time, by = df["id"], FUN = function(el) all(-1:-4 %in% el))
df <- merge(df, tags)
```

Result:

```
df
#    id time     x
# 1   1   -4  TRUE
# 2   1   -3  TRUE
# 3   1   -2  TRUE
# 4   1   -1  TRUE
# 5   2   -1 FALSE
# 6   2   -2 FALSE
# 7   2   -1 FALSE
# 8   2   -3 FALSE
# 9   3   -1  TRUE
# 10  3   -2  TRUE
# 11  3   -3  TRUE
# 12  3   -4  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

To add more options, here is a `data.table` one, which should have significant performance benefits:

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)[, tag := all(-1:-4 %in% time), by = id]
```

Result:

```
dt
#     id time   tag
#  1:  1   -4  TRUE
#  2:  1   -3  TRUE
#  3:  1   -2  TRUE
#  4:  1   -1  TRUE
#  5:  2   -1 FALSE
#  6:  2   -2 FALSE
#  7:  2   -1 FALSE
#  8:  2   -3 FALSE
#  9:  3   -1  TRUE
# 10:  3   -2  TRUE
# 11:  3   -3  TRUE
# 12:  3   -4  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base solution using `vapply` and `.subset2` (less readable than `$` or `[]` but far more efficient)

```
rb[['tag']] <- 0L
id_col <- .subset2(rb, 1L)
vapply(unique(rb$id), 
       function (id) {
         index <- id_col == id
         test <- all(sort(.subset2(rb, 2L)[index]) == -4:-1)
         rb[['tag']][index] <<- as.integer(test)
         test
         }, 
       logical(1))
rb
#    id time tag
# 1   1   -4   1
# 2   1   -3   1
# 3   1   -2   1
# 4   1   -1   1
# 5   2   -1   0
# 6   2   -2   0
# 7   3   -1   0
# 8   3   -3   0
# 9   4   -1   1
# 10  4   -2   1
# 11  4   -3   1
# 12  4   -4   1
```